# C program to subtract differing numbers from an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I want to crate a program that will subtract a decreasing set of numbers. or in other words:

I an array i have the numbers {20,23,67,3,67,12,24}

There are 7 elements in the array so therefore i want to to this:

20 - 7

23 - 6

67 - 5

3  - 4

67 - 3

12 - 2

24 - 1

I would assume I need to use a loop but am not sure of how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to write back the results? Or just display it?

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no specific count of items for arrays, length is fixed. If do you know the size 7 and create the array with the fixed length you can use the below code. You can use pointers for dynamic length arrays, but it is complicated.

```
int a[7] = {20,23,67,3,67,12,24};
int i;
for(i=7;i>0;i--) {
    printf("%d - %d \n", a[i-1], i);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `a[7-i]`?

Comment: No, the loop starts with 7 and decreases i by 1 in every iteration. Notice i-- and the i>0

Comment: Your code prints the array values in the reverse order that OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a counter at 0 and go through the array until you hit the null terminator and it will print your array in a the order in which it is stored as.